# how to implement two way communicate between android server and android client

Tags: android, sockets, communication

I have two android devices.One acting as server and the other acting as client.My client  device is able to send data to the server device using socket programming.I want my server device to send some acknowledgement/data to the client device.How to implement two way communication between android server and android client??Any help will be of great use.Thank you.

Comment: library suggestion: https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/ it handles most of the complication for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wifi direct to achieve this . One sample example is available in api level 17 provided by android(android-sdk/samples/android-17/WiFiDirectDemo).

Comment: Hi Amith.Can you please post the solution to the problem